# jquery .each() add individual attribute to a div

Tags: jquery, attributes, each

On load, i am looking to add a data-slide attribute number to each div found of the same class

for example:

```
<div class='slide' data-slide=''></div>
<div class='slide' data-slide=''></div>
<div class='slide' data-slide=''></div>
```

I am trying using the following code, however all it does is take the lnumber found rather than the index:

```
$( ".slide" ).each(function( index ) {
$('.slide').attr( 'data-slide',''+index+'');
});
```

I would like it to produce the following:

```
<div class='slide' data-slide='1'></div>
<div class='slide' data-slide='2'></div>
<div class='slide' data-slide='3'></div>
```

ANy ideas please?

Comment: All fantastic answers, and im sillt for not addingthe this! I blame friday afternoons! thanks all!

Comment: You want to select the answer below with a checkmark that helped you @PHPDev76

Answer (score 9):

The [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) takes a function as the second argument which can return the values that has to be assigned to the attribute

```
$(".slide").attr('data-slide', function (index) {
    return index + 1;
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/sMM3M/)

Answer (score 3):

Inside the `each()` block, `this` will refer to the current element in the iteration.

```
$(".slide").each(function(index) {
    $(this).attr('data-slide', index + 1);
});
```

Comment: Someone is just downvoting half the answers today :\

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan you may want to add 1 to the index

Answer (score 2):

<strike>[**Fiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/PEvkf/)</strike>

```
$(".slide").each(function (index) {
    $(this).data('slide', index);
});
```

[**Updated Fiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/PEvkf/2)

```
$(".slide").each(function (index) {
    $(this).attr('data-slide', index+1);
});
```

Comment: you're adding jQuery data attributes. He's trying to add attributes to the markup.

Comment: This won't be visible in the markup as `data-*` puts the value in the cache, not the DOM. You need to use `attr`

Comment: @j08691 OP does, `I would like it to produce the following:`. If he's using an attribute selector it needs to be visible in the DOM.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - I believe he's after the end result, whether or not it can be seen in the markup.